# Bartle's theorem 7.6: If () is Cauchy in measure, there exists a subsequence () of () such that () converges a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

[image]

I'm having trouble understanding this passage of Bartle's Elements of Integration, chapter 7, theorem:

*Theorem 7.6: Let* $(f_n)$ *be a sequence of measurable real-valued functions which is Cauchy in measure. Then there exists a subsequence which is converges almost everywhere and in measure to a measurable real-valued function* $f$.

I can see how it would be this way if the sets were disjoint, because then we would have $\mu(\cup_{j=k}^{\infty}E_k)=\sum_{j=k}^{\infty}\mu(E_k) $. Also I can see that $\mu(E_n\cap E_m) < 2^{-max\{n,m\}}$ but I'm failing to understand how the whole measure of $F_k$ will be less than $2^{-(k-1)}$.

If anyone could help me, I would be most grateful

Answer (score 1):

Use subadditivity:
$$\mu(F_k) = \mu\left(\bigcup_{j=k}^{\infty}E_j\right)
\leq \sum_{j=k}^{\infty}\mu(E_j) \leq \sum_{j=k}^{\infty}2^{-j} = 2^{-k+1}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}2^{-j} = 2^{-k+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is probaly too late, but you could define $E'_j=E_j\setminus (E_{j-1}\cup...\cup E_k)$ for all $j\geq k$. In this case, we have $\dot{\cup}_{j\geq k} E_j'=\cup_{j\geq k} E_j$. I will drop the $j\geq k$ from now on. But basically:

$$\mu(\cup_j E_j')=\sum_j \mu(E_j')$$

Because $E_j'\subset E_j$, we have $\mu(E_j)=\mu(E_j')+\mu(E_j\setminus E_j')\geq \mu(E_j')$:

$$\mu(\cup_j E_j')=\sum_j \mu(E_j')\leq \sum_j \mu(E_j)\leq 2^{-k+1}$$

Fun fact: we studied Analysis I with Bianca Morelli together. It is nice to see you here. :)